# Скачать файл через WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-webview, xamarin.android

У меня в `WebView` задана публичная ссылка с Яндекс диска, всё в принципе работает как и задумал, кроме одного — скачивание файла.

[image: демонстрация проблемы]

Я думал, что всего-навсего нужно перехватить ссылку на файл в `WebView_Navigating`, но он не срабатывает в этом случае.

Я просмотрел уже, наверное, сотню вариантов в интернете, но ни один из них мне так и не помог.

Потом, в исходных данных страницы нашел такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Методом "тыка" стал удалять поочередно эти методы и пробовать нажимать "скачать" и узнал, что как только удаляю `react-dom.min.js`, то кнопка "скачать" перестает работать.

Посмотрел в этом `js` строку 40, увидел такое:

```
b.addEventListener(a, c, !0)
}

function xf(a, b) {
    yf(oc, a, b)
}

function oc(a, b) {
    if (qc) {
        var c = kd(b);
        c = dc(c);
        null === c || "number" !== typeof c.tag || 2 === wb(c) || (c = null);
        if (rc.length) {
            var d = rc.pop();
            d.topLevelType = a;
            d.nativeEvent = b;
            d.targetInst = c;
            a = d
        } else a = {
            topLevelType: a,
            nativeEvent: b,
            targetInst: c,
            ancestors: []
        };
        try {
            Xe(Uh, a)
        } finally {
            a.topLevelType = null, a.nativeEvent = null, a.targetInst = null, a.ancestors.length = 0, 10 > rc.length && rc.push(a)
        }
    }
}

function zf(a) {
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, sc) || (a[sc] = Vh++, Af[a[sc]] = {});
```

Я надеялся найти хоть что-то, что поможет мне, но всё тщетно.

Также пробовал "прикидываться" компьютером, поменяв `UserAgent` — открывается версия для ПК, но проблемы все те же.

Толкните, пожалуйста, на путь истинный, не может быть такое, что это нереально осуществить.

У меня даже нет цели скачивать через свое приложение, имея `url` на файл, я бы передавал его в браузер на скачивание, но выцепить его никак не удается.

p.s: мне уже помогали здесь с поиском прямых ссылок на изображение, но в этом случае, мне нужно делать всё именно через `WebView`, так как через него удобно просматривать фото/видео.

Comment: `мне нужно делать всё именно через WebView, так как через него удобно просматривать фото/видео` - вы сам себе злобный буратино, сами суете палки в колеса. Вам сайт дает прямую ссылку на нужный файл в виде JSON, в чем проблема составить список, а дальше, если хотите, отправлять ее на просмотр в WebView или еще куда? Ну а имея ссылку, скачать труда ведь не составит (хотя не знаю как там с видео)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, но в таком случае у меня же не будет удобного просмотра содержимого публичной ссылки, т.к там могут быть и фото и видео, а на сайте яндекса всё это есть.